# how to let npm package bin run with experimental-modules option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, es6-modules

Starting in Node v8.5.0, support for ES6 style modules

```
import x from 'x'
```

has been available by running node using the option `--experimental-modules`, as below:

`node --experimental-modules test.mjs`

Using the `bin` key in `package.json` you can easily create cli tools [npm cli](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm), by running `npm link`.

Unfortunately, when running in this manner, node is called without the optional `--experimental-modules` flag.

How can you use `bin` modules with `--experimental-modules`?

Here is an example

**bin/healthcheck.mjs**

```
import { connect } from 'amqplib'

let open = connect(process.env.RABBITMQ_URL);

const exit = ({healthy = true}) => {
  return healthy ? process.exit(0) : process.exit(1)
}

open.then(() => {
  exit({healthy: true})
}).catch((e) => {
  exit({healthy: false})
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-cli",
  "bin": {
    "healthcheck": "./bin/healthcheck.mjs"
  }
}
```

**running...**

```
> npm link
> healthcheck
/usr/local/bin/healthcheck: line 1: import: command not found
/usr/local/bin/healthcheck: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/healthcheck: line 3: `let open = connect(process.env.RABBITMQ_URL);'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a shebang at the top of the script

```
#!/bin/sh 
":" //# comment; exec /usr/bin/env node --experimental-modules "$0" "$@"
```

More details here: http://sambal.org/2014/02/passing-options-node-shebang-line/

Comment: Sorcery! Thank you very much. =)

Comment: Nice Patrick!  In my simple use case, I just have this one-liner at the top of my entry-point file: `#!/usr/bin/env node --experimental-modules --no-warnings`. Thanks!

Comment: it's shameful that in 2019, node still requires us to use this hack from early 2014 — so glad it works!

Comment: I get this error when it runs `line 2: //#: No such file or directory`. It continues running when I run it from Terminal, but it errs out in Sourcetree. Any idea if there is a way to solve? I removed "comment", and that didn't help.

Comment: Oops--nevermind--I see it was my adding a semicolon after ":"... Can't do that apparently